# Use .DefaultIfEmpty() instead of .FirstOrDefault() ?? String.Empty;

Tags: c#, linq

How can I integrate the `.DefaultIfEmpty()` extension method so I have **not** to use

```
.FirstOrDefault() ?? String.Empty;
```

Code:

```
(from role in roleList
let roleArray = role.RoleId.Split(new char[] { WorkflowConstants.WorkflowRoleDelimiter })
where roleArray.Length.Equals(_SplittedRoleIdArrayLength) && 
      HasAccessToCurrentUnit(roleArray[_UnitIndexInRoleId])
select roleArray[_LevelIndexInRoleId]).FirstOrDefault() ?? String.Empty;
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't. `DefaultIfEmpty` is interested in enumerables, not scalar values. Create your own extension method, possibly named also `FirstOrDefault` that takes a `T` argument to specify as the default.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use:

```
var query = ...;

return query.DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty).First();
```

But this doesn't reduce the complexity IMO.

Comment: Yes reducing the complexity is one of my goals. Any other suggestion so far you have?

Comment: Hi, Mr. 2k. Now you are in fact 14k!

Comment: I switched to your solution.

Comment: That won't translate with Linq-to-entities.  It will fail with error: "The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead". I recently had to replace `DefaultIfEmpty().First()` with `FirstOrDefault()`, which should achieve the same result.

Comment: @Triynko In the OP's case, it will work fine because those operations _are_ the final query operation. The exception occurs if you try to use them in subqueries. For this question, the desired output is an empty string - not null - when the sequence has no results, so ken2k's answer is correct.

Answer (score 6):

If you're interested in extension method then you could use something like this:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static string FirstOrEmpty(this IEnumerable<string> source)
    {
        return source.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

This method isn't generic because then we'd have to use `default(T)` and it'll give us `null` instead of `string.Empty`.

Comment: maybe then `T FirstOrEmpty(this IEnumerable<T> source)`

Comment: @Ilya Ivanov, if it'll be generic then it's default still would be null for string.

Comment: But `T FirstOrDefault(this IEnumerable<T> source, T default)` would be possible. Then again, `.FirstOrDefault(string.Empty)` vs. `.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty` doesn't really make that much of a difference.

Comment: @hvd, I have to admit that this was my first thought but after that I decided that `FirstOrEmpty` could give clearer output code.

Answer (score 2):

I found this course on PluralSight interesting and I remembered it when I saw this question.

You could watch the whole course, but the Map Reduce and `Option<T>` strategies especially with DefaultIfEmpty seemed like it could be a good fit to your use case.

**Tactical Design Patterns in .NET: Control Flow
by Zoran Horvat**
https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/tactical-design-patterns-dot-net-control-flow/table-of-contents

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
var query=(
    from role in roleList
    let delimiter=WorkflowConstants.WorkflowRoleDelimiter
    let roleArray=role.RoleId.Split(new char[] { delimiter })
    where roleArray.Length.Equals(_SplittedRoleIdArrayLength)
    where HasAccessToCurrentUnit(roleArray[_UnitIndexInRoleId])
    select roleArray[_LevelIndexInRoleId]
    ).DefaultIfEmpty("").FirstOrDefault();
```

For the suspicion about the semantic meaning of `DefaultIfEmpty` and `FirstOrDefault`, following is the code decompiled from the library:

- Code

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<TSource> DefaultIfEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
  {
      return source.DefaultIfEmpty<TSource>(default(TSource));
  }

  public static IEnumerable<TSource> DefaultIfEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource defaultValue)
  {
      if (source == null)
      {
          throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
      }
      return DefaultIfEmptyIterator<TSource>(source, defaultValue);
  }

  public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
  {
      if (source == null)
      {
          throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
      }
      IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
      if (list != null)
      {
          if (list.Count > 0)
          {
              return list[0];
          }
      }
      else
      {
          using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
          {
              if (enumerator.MoveNext())
              {
                  return enumerator.Current;
              }
          }
      }
      throw Error.NoElements();
  }

  public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
  {
      if (source == null)
      {
          throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
      }
      IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
      if (list != null)
      {
          if (list.Count > 0)
          {
              return list[0];
          }
      }
      else
      {
          using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
          {
              if (enumerator.MoveNext())
              {
                  return enumerator.Current;
              }
          }
      }
      return default(TSource);
  }
  ```

And here are something to mention:

1. `DefaultIfEmpty` has a parameterless overload, which invokes the parameterized overload with `default(TSource)` and return its result.
2. The only difference between parameterless `FirstOrDefault` and `First`, is the latter would throw when the collection is empty.

   For more information, see [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<TSource> Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) on MSDN.
3. `FirstOrDefault` semantically expressed `first or default`, and so called; it's not named `first or null`. In c#, `default(T)` for a reference type is *null*, but for non-reference type, it's not. For example, `default(int)` is zero.

   The keyword `default` was never said *null* semantically. It's **DEFAULT**.

   Also, for more information, [default Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Your FirstOrDefault(); at the end makes no sense. If you expected a null value by OrDefault then your sequence is empty. Then the "" will be returned... I suggest .First() instead.

Comment: @Elisa: Yes, they are the same here, since I just copy from your code and not changed, but I think that doesn't matter.

Comment: Well it does matter. Using FirstOrDefault is only 50% right. The OrDefault (null value) will never happen and give the reader a false impression of whats the code doing.

Comment: of course the null value is only "OrDefault"/default value for non-value types like integer. Thanks for the revision. 1 vote up.

Comment: Correction from above comment: "...for non-value types not like integer".

Comment: @Elisa: It's okay. I usually delete comments after whom I talked to has read it, except those does matter.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6 introduces the concept of being able to pass in what the default value should be, should the item not be found. So for example, this code is now valid in .NET 6:

```
source.FirstOrDefault(String.Empty);
```

Or:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
var custom = numbers.FirstOrDefault(-1);
```

> In the example above we don't need to be reliant on getting back 0
> which is the default for int anymore. This could be handy when 0 is a
> valid number in the context of using the list of numbers where as -1
> isn't.

You can read more:

https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/09/02/linq-ordefault-enhancements-in-net-6/
https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/default-your-firstordefault-in-net6.0